# Unity - Platform falling on collision

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've just started with Unity and trying a simple 2D game. I have a ball above a platform. Both the ball and the platform have a Rigidbody and Box Collision component. The gravity for the Platform is set to 0 so that it doesn't fall.

However, when the ball falls on the platform, both the ball and the platform falls below.

How can I keep the platform stable and not fall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the rigidBody2D of the platform to  static?

RigidBody2D -> Body Type -> Static

Else the collision with the ball will apply a force to the platform, gravity = 0 doesn't mean that the platform can't move. Alternatively you could also do:

RigidBody2D -> Constraint -> Freeze position x, position y, rotation z.